# Creating a network packet hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, networking, inheritance, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I've been tasked with developing a simple packet analysis tool using Java. I'm given a wrapper that allows me to capture Ethernet frames from a network interface as byte arrays.

Currently, I'm trying to implement a packet hierarchy. I have a Packet class that stores the src/dst MAC addresses and the ethertype, then places the remaining contents of the frame in a separate byte array.

My question is this: from this point, I want to be able to create a new object, say of type IPPacket, where the data used to create said packet is the remaining data from the Ethernet frame (beginning with the "4/6" for IP version). I am currently doing this by setting a Boolean called isIP, which is based on the ethertype (0x800 for IPv4).

In my constructor for the Packet object, the final line is a call to this method:

```
    private void createPacket(){
        if(isIP == true)
            new IPPacket(payload);
        else if(isARP == true)
            new ARPPacket(payload);
    }
```

where payload is a byte array containing the stripped Ethernet frame.

This method is not working properly, because when I try to process the IPPacket object, I am receiving null pointer exceptions when trying to access bytes within the array.

Is there a clean way to get my desired result? I'm hoping to be able to simply create Packet objects that can cascade through my packet hierarchy, creating objects of the appropriate packet subtype (ARP, IP, TCP, UDP), and then be displayed to the user. Eventually, the IPPacket class will have TCPPacket and UDPPacket as child classes.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what about using [Jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/)?

Comment: JPcap isn't an option, as the project assignment specifically states "no outside packages may be used."

Answer (score 1):

In your `createPacket` method you create either a new `IPPacket` instance or a new `ARPPacket` instance. But you don't save a reference to either of these. This means, these new instance can be immediately garbage collected. Therefore I think, your `NullPointerException` does **not** happen when you try to access the playload **but** one step before when you try to access `IPPacket` or `ARPPacket`.